# Getting absolute file path with q-file Quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm newbie in coding. I builded a project works on Windows platform to process ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) commands to devices connected via USB. I used Quasar&Vue for UI and Go Lang for processing ADB commands in the backend. In Quasar Framework, I found q-file component to pick files from PC, and want to send absolute path of any APK file to backend with http calls, then Go do the rest by reading and installing that APK file to my Android device. (Needed path example: C:\Users\Cenk\Downloads\Whatsapp.apk)

I added console logging at the point I picked file, can not see any path info as shown below.

[image: Console Log]

The code I used for that purpose is below. Can anyone help me about how can I get the absolute path of any selected file with q-file or should I use any other component to do it?

```html
<q-file filled 
  bottom-slots 
  v-model="file" 
  label="Dosya Seç" 
  counter 
  max-files="12" 
  accept=".apk"
>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <q-icon v-if="file !== null" 
      name="close" 
      @click.stop.prevent="file = null" 
      class="cursor-pointer"
    />
    <q-icon name="create_new_folder" 
      @click.stop.prevent
    />
  </template>
</q-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

use two object, one for image in blob and other to URL, use URL.createObjectURL for get URL from image file:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const fotos = ref(null)
const fotos = ref(null)
const fotosURL = ref([])
const slide = ref(1)

function obtenerURL () {
if (fotos.value) {
fotos.value.forEach(element => {
  fotosURL.value.push(URL.createObjectURL(element))
})
}
}

</script>

<q-file
  v-model="fotos"
  label="Seleccione los archivos"
  filled
  multiple
  accept=".jpg, image/*"
  style="max-width: 400px"
  @update:model-value="obtenerURL"
/>
<q-carousel
  animated
  v-model="slide"
  arrows
  navigation
  infinite
  v-if="fotosURL.length>0"
>
  <q-carousel-slide v-for="(img,id) in fotosURL" :key="id"
  :name="id+1" :img-src="img" />
</q-carousel>
```